# 400 Bad Request - Microsoft Translation API - Jooscript & Java

Tags: java, groovy, libreoffice, microsoft-translator, jodconverter

I use LibreOffice/JOD library to generate PDF files based on an ODT template I manually created.

These templates use jooscript to populate the template with values from the database. Two (2) of these database values are translated to Chinese.

One of these values is a **string which translates correctly**, however as of the **19th of May 2017 the other value, a datetime fails to convert.**

I receive a HTTP 400 Bad Request error message coming back from the API.

The translator page looks as below:

```
package com.anguillafsd.acorn.pam.conf;
import wslite.rest.*
import wslite.http.auth.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date;

import javax.management.monitor.Monitor.NumericalType;

import com.anguillafsd.acorn.pam.conf.NumericTranslator

import com.anguillafsd.acorn.pam.util.Translatable

class Translator implements Translatable{

def id = *********
def secret = *********
def getToken = {
    def client = new RESTClient("https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13")

    try{
        client.post(){
            type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            urlenc client_id:id , client_secret:secret , scope: "http://api.microsofttranslator.com", grant_type: "client_credentials"
        }.json.access_token
    }
    catch(e){ e.printStackTrace(); return null;}

}

public String translate(String text, String from, String to){
    def client = new RESTClient("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate")
    client.get(path:'', query:[text:"$text", from:"$from", to:"$to"], headers:["Authorization":"Bearer ${getToken()}"]).xml
}

public String translateDate(Date date,String to){
    def numericTranslator = new NumericTranslator()
    def df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy")
    def txt = translate(df.format(date), 'en', to)
    def yearMatch = (txt =~ /(\d{4})/)
    yearMatch.each {key,value -> key.each { txt = txt.replaceFirst(it, numericTranslator.translate(Long.parseLong(it),to)) }}

    def otherMatch = (txt =~ /\d{1,2}/)
    otherMatch.each{value -> txt = txt.replaceFirst(value,numericTranslator.translate(Long.parseLong(value),to))}
    return txt
}

public String translateNumber(BigInteger number, String to) {
    def numericTranslator = new NumericTranslator()
    numericTranslator.translate(number,to)
}

}
```

The jooscript used to translate the datetime is as follows with `certificate.issueDate` being the database variable.

```
${translate(certificate.issueDate?datetime,"en","zh-CHT" )}
```

The format of `certificate.issueDate` is Date: dd-MON-yy

Any assistance is appreciated since this code remains unchanged and has been working for the last few years.

***Updated:***

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=06+December+2017&from=en&to=zh-CHT

Request : Translate?text=06+December+2017&from=en&to=zh-CHT

Found that when we change the text to anything it gives the same response, i.e. translating "Hello" would give the same error.

Expected response: 六　日　十二　月　二零一七年,i.e. 6 day, 12 month,2017 year. although the format is changed using SimpleDateFormat to dd MMM yyyy.

Comment: Update your question to have a Fiddler or Charles trace of your request and response. (i.e. the actual request and response in text format)  That's what's really needed here.

Comment: What is the response type you are expecting from http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate? Is it application/x-`www-form-urlencoded` or something else?